# HERE SDK Orientation change too late

Tags: heremaps, heremaps-android-sdk, heremap-navigation

I am using HERE-Android-SDK to build a simple navigation solution with offline maps.
In order to automatically center and rotate the map (depending on location and orientation of the user) I am using the `PositioningManager` class from the HERE-SDK. It seems that the orientation update is some seconds too late when an active navigation is running.

I am using the following code snippets to do so.

```
val positioningManager = PositioningManager.getInstance()
positioningManager.addListener(WeakReference(positionListener))
positioningManager.start(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS)

 var positionListener = object : PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener {
        override fun onPositionFixChanged(
            p0: PositioningManager.LocationMethod?,
            p1: PositioningManager.LocationStatus?
        ) {
           // do nothing here
        }

        override fun onPositionUpdated(
            method: PositioningManager.LocationMethod?,
            position: GeoPosition?,
            isMapMatched: Boolean
        ) {
            if (position == null) return
            // update map center and orientation
        }
    }
```

```
override fun onPause() {
  positioningManager.stop()
}
```

```
override fun onResume() {
  positioningManager.start(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS)
}
```

Is there anything I can do to avoid the too late orientation update?
Thanks for all of your help in advance!

Comment: This is the Premium SDK? Try to consider moving to the newer 4.x Navigate Edition. It is much simpler to use.

Comment: Yep, this is the premium SDK - is there no option without migrate to the 4.x version?